# Round Float Value Based On Condiiton

Tags: python-3.x

I need to round Value based on certain conditions, please check below.

When Value comes in like

- 21.43 round to - 21
- 21.65 round to - 22
- 21.5 round to - 21.5

Answer (score 2):

Use the `round` function plus an if statement:

```py
myNum = 21.43
if mynum % 1 != 0.5:
  myNum = round(myNum)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can utilize the [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) function

> Return number rounded to ndigits precision after the decimal point. If ndigits is omitted or is None, it returns the nearest integer to its input.
> For the built-in types supporting round(), values are rounded to the closest multiple of 10 to the power minus ndigits; if two multiples are equally close, rounding is done toward the even choice (so, for example, both round(0.5) and round(-0.5) are 0, and round(1.5) is 2). Any integer value is valid for ndigits (positive, zero, or negative). The return value is an integer if ndigits is omitted or None. Otherwise the return value has the same type as number

As an example, `round(21.43)` returns `21`.